# Как установить apk файл на 11 Android с помощью java

Tags: java, android-studio

С толкнулся с такой проблемой, что при установке apk файла на 11 Android вылезает "Не удалось обработать пакет", перепробовал несколько способов с FileProvider, но всё-равно получаю такую ошибку. Пишу на java в Android Studio. Буду благодарен, если вы напишите свой пример установки apk файла;)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
build.gradle
`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nevskiy619.launcher"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

`
AndroidManifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.nevskiy619.launcher">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sentrium"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".InstallActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="com.nevskiy619.launcher.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Сам код

```
case R.id.buttonClient:
    boolean isNonPlayAppAllowed = false;
                try {
                    isNonPlayAppAllowed = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;
                } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
                if (!isNonPlayAppAllowed) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));
                } else {
                    installApk();
                    buttonComplete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
break;
    public void installApk() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.nevskiy619.launcher.provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + "1client.apk" )), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    
            startActivity(intent);
                    /*File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + "1client.apk");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                        Uri uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.nevskiy619.launcher.provider", file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE");
                        intent.setData(uriForFile);
                        intent.setFlags(1);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return;
                    }
                    Uri fromFile = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                    intent2.setDataAndType(fromFile, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent2.setFlags(268435456);
                    startActivity(intent2);*/
        }
```

Файл provider_paths

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <external-path name="external_download" path="Download"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите build gradle

Comment: @ArtyMorris Всё показал, пожалуйста посмотрите